# Looking for Euclid's Elements with mathematical commentary

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

Is there a book somewhere that contains Euclid's Elements alongside mathematical commentary? I have Heath's translation of Euclid's Elements, but it contains mostly historical commentary, not mathematical commentary. I would be very grateful if there was a book, or perhaps an online source, that contains what I am looking for.

Comment: Online, at least on Google Books, you can find "The First Six Books of the Elements" by John Casey from the late 1800s, which has a fair amount of commentary, alternate constructions, and associated theorems. It's just the plane geometry.